# How to return directory (Xquery path) as a value and not as a string of that path?

Tags: xquery, where-clause, nodes, clause, basex

When writing this code for Basex

```
<tourism>
{
  for $hotel in doc("tourism.xml")/tourism/hotel
  let $r:=$hotel/room
  let $g:=doc("tourism.xml")/tourism/guest
  where $g/@name="Udo Lindenberg" and $g/customer/@hotel=$hotel/@id and $r/@id=$g/occupies/@room
  return
    <hotel>
        <hotel_name>{string($hotel/@name)}</hotel_name>
          <first_day>$g/occupies/@from</first_day>
          <last_day>$g/occupies/@to</last_day>
    </hotel>
}
</tourism>
```

It returns this:

```
<tourism>
  <hotel>
    <hotel_name>Interconti</hotel_name>
    <first_day>$g/occupies/@from</first_day>
    <last_day>$g/occupies/@to</last_day>
  </hotel>
  <hotel>
    <hotel_name>Tourist Inn</hotel_name>
    <first_day>$g/occupies/@from</first_day>
    <last_day>$g/occupies/@to</last_day>
  </hotel>
```

How to return "2004-03-21" "2004-05-05", Instead of $g/occupies/@from $g/occupies/@to ?

Comment: Please add a small sample test data set, i.e. your `toursim.xml`. Without data, we can't help you much. However, the error message already pretty much tells you all about it: In your where clause you use a path expression (i.e., `/`), but at least one of this expressions does not return a node. And you can't use path expressions on strings, they only make sense on nodes.

Comment: Also, I would strongly suggest you rephrase the title, because it sounds a lot like BaseX is at fault here (i.e. somehow misbehaving or contains a bug), while clearly your code is simply not valid XQuery.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [how to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). So far, your questions are lacking basic information.

Comment: Ok, I will take these notes into consideration next time. @dirkk thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `doc` in `let $g:=("tourism.xml")/tourism/guest`. (Should be `let $g:=doc("tourism.xml")/tourism/guest`) Looks like you're also missing some `{}` in `first_day` and `last_day`. Even if those are all corrected, I don't think your XQuery is going to work. You should add an example of what output you're expecting so someone can suggest an alternative XQuery.

Comment: Thanks for good point I missed.
Right now I get output like this:
<tourism>
  <hotel>
    <hotel_name>Interconti</hotel_name>
    <first_day>$g/occupies/@from</first_day>
    <last_day>$g/occupies/@to</last_day>
  </hotel>
  <hotel>
    <hotel_name>Tourist Inn</hotel_name>
    <first_day>$g/occupies/@from</first_day>
    <last_day>$g/occupies/@to</last_day>
  </hotel>
</tourism>

Now I need to convert $g/occupies/@from into string, or int, which I don't know how to do

Comment: As Daniel Haley correctly pointed out, you are missing braces `{}` around these expressions. You do use them for `hotel_name`, but not for the other two elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Missing {} in the `return` for `first_day` and `last_day`. Sample XML structure would be of great help, as suggested by @dirkk

```
<tourism>
{
  for $hotel in doc("tourism.xml")/tourism/hotel
  let $r:=$hotel/room
  let $g:=doc("tourism.xml")/tourism/guest
    where $g/@name="Udo Lindenberg" and $g/customer/@hotel=$hotel/@id and $r/@id=$g /occupies/@room
  return
  <hotel>
    <hotel_name>{string($hotel/@name)}</hotel_name>
      <first_day>{$g/occupies/@from}</first_day>
      <last_day>{$g/occupies/@to}</last_day>
  </hotel>
}
</tourism>
```